# 'npm install' failing, after setting up git clone. Despite fully upgraded npm & node

Tags: node.js, github, npm, terminal, three.js

I am trying to install npm in a three.js project that is coming from this github page:
https://github.com/visionary-3d/shaders-crash-course

I noticed the problem after cloning the github project:

`git clone https://github.com/visionary-3d/shaders-crash-course.git`

This was all done succesfully, however, then I tried to run `npm install`

But the terminal responds with this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YchmI.png)

I am really bad reading the terminal, so I don't really understand what it means, or if I perhaps need to download something. Maybe the package `package: 'eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.13.1',`, which is being described in the error message.

This is the package.json file that came with the Github project

```
{
  "name": "three-boilerplate",
  "version": "3.0.1",
  "description": "Three.js webpack 5 boilerplate using Babel and PostCSS and Gsap.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Arya",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js",
    "lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.js' || true",
    "prettify": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.js'"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "three",
    "three webpack",
    "three webpack 5",
    "three webpack boilerplate",
    "webpack",
    "webpack 5"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.43.5",
    "sass-loader": "^12.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.58.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:visionary-studio/three-boilerplate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.7",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001441",
    "gsap": "^3.11.4",
    "three": "^0.148.0"
  }
}
```

At first i thought it was because of my node.js and npm versions, so I updated them to:

```
node: 20.5.0
npm: 9.8.1
```

With these commands:

```
nvm install node
sudo npm update -g npm
```

But this did not help.

The terminal is not my friend, and I don't understand what is happening, I hope someone can help.

Comment: Add the error message as plain text instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you provided clearly indicates that the version of node you are running is not supported by eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.13.1 you slould run nvm use 16 then run mpm i

Answer (score 0):

Use administrator mode to run the command as it's related to the file permission

In mac, simply use sudo :
It's safer to use the `sudo npm install` command in Terminal instead of enabling the root user.

In Windows pc run the cmd as administrator and run command `npm install`

in Linux you can either use `sudo npm install` with password or you can login as root user